# Unable to execute Java Robot class in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos-big-sur, awtrobot

I am trying to execute a simple Selenium program with Robot class in my macOS BigSur(Version 11.5.1).
My Robot class is not getting executed, there is a java icon which pops up and then quickly closes.

I tried to give java.exe access to my full desk, accessibility in my System Preferences privacy setting, but nothing works.
Can anyone pls help?

The following is my code:

```
@Test
public void newTab() throws AWTException {

    driver.findElement(By.id("email_field")).sendKeys("admin123@gmail.com");;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password_field']")).sendKeys("admin123");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Login to Account']"));

    Robot r=new Robot();
     r.delay(200);
    // Press Enter
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    r.delay(500);
    // Release Enter
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

}
```